# Create an event that starts if the page makes any sound?

Tags: javascript

I need to create an event that starts if the page is making any sound, or if there is a file playing on it.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using some sort of player on the page? [YouTube, etc?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple way for your page to play a sound -- mostly via `<object>, <embed>` (though you can do it in an `<applet>` too!). Trouble is each one of these embeds a plugin in the page and each plugin has different parameters, and they are specific for each provider. And there is a multitude of them... And sound formats... so you could write a script that iterates through all these tags and finds all the parameters for them and try to figure out if this is a QuickTime plugin, or a real player, or windows media etc etc etc -- point being it will be a horrible function and it will still not cover all the cases. So I guess **NO** should be the short answer.

Comment: I think you accidentally a few words. I do agree on the end conclusion though. It is possible to detect if any plugins have been included on the page but there is no way of telling if those are actually playing sound.

Comment: i didn't miss those sorry, it seems that using a html tag withouth putting the code markers prints just that tag in-page. I've re-edited the answer and marked those tags as code.

Answer (score 0):

Only possible with HTML5 supporting browsers, but if you use the `<audio>` tag you have an event attibute at your disposal called `onplay`

If jQuery, you can do an each event bind for the `play` event for all audio tags on a page.

Try it:
http://jsfiddle.net/jdgiotta/rvpBj/